# lua function from c++

Tags: c++, lua

Let we have a code in "luafunc.lua":

```
function foo(a, b)
   return a + b
end

a = io.read('*n')
b = io.read('*n')
print (foo(a, b))
```

Let's try to use function foo from C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"{
    #include <lua.h>
    #include <lualib.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
};

int main()
{
    lua_State *lvm = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(lvm);
    luaL_loadfile(lvm, "luafunc.lua");

    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    lua_pcall(lvm, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
    lua_getglobal(lvm, "foo");
    lua_pushnumber(lvm, a);
    lua_pushnumber(lvm, b);
    if (lua_pcall(lvm, 2, 1, 0))
    {
        cout << "Error: " << lua_tostring(lvm, -1) << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "The result is: " << lua_tonumber(lvm, -1) << endl;

    lua_close(lvm);
    return 0;
}
```

So, the problem is that this C++ code executes the whole luafunc.lua. Naturally I can remove reading part from lua-file and then from C++ only foo is executed. But can I use function foo from C++ even if there's other stuff in lua-file?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to be able to use that function without also running that code, separate the code and function into two separate scripts, a script with `foo` in it and a script that loads that script and tests `foo`.

A function is not defined until the script containing it is *executed*. Executing that script will define `foo` and then run the other 3 lines as well.

When you load a file with [loaL_loadfile](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_loadfile) (or any of the other load calls) the entire script is turned into a function; to execute it you have to call that function, with [lua_pcall](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_pcall) or whatever.  Until then the script that defines foo is just an unnamed, unexecuted chunk of code on the stack.

There is no function to execute just part of a script, or execute only the function definitions.

Comment: You can load code without executing it, via Lua or the API. In the OP's case, `luaL_loadfile` loads it without executing it, leaving a compiled "chunk" on the stack. He then executes it on the following line (`lua_pcall`).

Comment: @Mud: Will that allow him to call `foo` without executing the global code?  Doesn't sound like that solves the problem.

Comment: No, not at all. He's going to need to execute the chunk for `foo` to be defined at all, because functions are defined at runtime in Lua. Your answer solves his problem. I was clarifying that your statement "there's no way to get lua to **load that file** without also executing the code" is not technically correct. Loading a file and executing it are separate steps in the OP's program, and you can do the same in Lua with `load` or `loadfile` which both load and compile a Lua script without executing it (`dofile` loads, compiles and executes a script).

Answer (score 3):

> can I use function foo from C++ even if there's other stuff in lua-file?

Yes.

Can you use it without executing the other parts of that file? No.

Lua functions are defined at runtime. Simply loading and compiling that script is not enough, you have to run the resulting chunk for `foo` to be defined in your Lua state.